# Rails 3 - Nested Forms and Default Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, default-value, nested-attributes

I am trying to create form that contains another model in rails. I have accomplished this with using accepts_nested_attibutes and it is working great. The problem is I have an additional field in that table that records the User Name for each comment and I am not sure on how to insert that information when a new comment is being created. The username is being supplied by the Application Controller using the "current_user" method.

Regards,
Kyle

**Comment Model**

```
    class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :post
     before_save :set_username

    private
     def set_username
      self.created_by = current_user
     end
    end
```

**Application Controller** (This is just a Sandbox app so I just put a string in the method)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
    "FName LName"
  end

end
```

**Show View**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>
<div id="show_comments"><%= render 'comments' %></div>
<div id="add_comments">
    Add Comment
    <%= form_for @post, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @post.id}, :html => { :'data-type' => 'html', :id => 'create_comment_form' } do |f| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :comments, @new_comment do |comment_fields| %>
            <%= comment_fields.text_area :content %>
        <%end%>
      <div class="validation-error"></div>
      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**Post Controller**

```
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        @comments = @post.comments.all
        format.html { redirect_to({:action => :show, :id => @post.id}, :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: did you look at: http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2 ?

Comment: I did and I wasn't able to find anything that would help me here.

Comment: you should provide your comments form code

Comment: Added the code to the article

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was originally thinking you could just set it as a default or a before_save in the model. But models don't have access to `current_user`. So it's probably best to just set the current user in the controller. It's not as DRY as putting it in the model but it's less hackey and potentially problematic this way.

```
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.attributes = params[:post]
  @post.comments.each do |comment|
    comment.created_by = current_user if comment.new_record?
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      @comments = @post.comments.all
      format.html { redirect_to({:action => :show, :id => @post.id}, :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: a bit overkill but worth noticing, +1 :)

Comment: When I try that one I get "undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Comment:0x104ee4cb0>". It looks like its not able to access the Method from the Application Controller.

Comment: If I put a string in there it works perfectly but this will vary depending on who is logged into the application

Comment: You're right. I had forgotten that current_user isn't available from the scope of the model. So I've changed my answer to setting the user in the controller where current_user is available.

Comment: The problem with that is I am setting the created by on the comment not the post. The Comment is nested in the Post

Comment: I could make it a hidden field but I do not want to have to do that since it could be edited by the user

Comment: Okay, third times a charm. I think my mind already decided to start the weekend early today. Anyway, if you use `attributes=` instead of `update_attributes` and then loop through the comments and set the created_by, it should work. I think :)

Comment: So at first glance this looked like it was working but I realized it listed all the comments for that post as the current user. It should have only listed the current user for the new comment.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking create and not update for some reason. I've added a `if comment.new_record?` condition to the code above that should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to point out that it is possible to access `current_user` in the model scope. In this case I don think it is necessary, as the solution from @aNoble should work. So if is possible to set the current_user from the controller, I would prefer that.

In short, we add a method to the `User` class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_accessor :current_user

  def self.current_user
    @current_user ||= User.new("dummy-user")
  end
  ...
end
```

and in your application controllor, we add a `before_filter` that sets it. Make sure to call this filter after your authentication is done.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter { |c| User.current_user = current_user }

end
```

And, then inside your `Comment`-model you could just do something like

```
class Comment

  before_create :set_user

  def set_user
    created_by = User.current_user unless created_by
  end
end
```

(so I only set the `created_by` if it was not yet set, and only upon creation of a new comment).